# Custom Adapter checkbox not checked when search

Tags: android, adapter, custom-adapter

I am facing this issue, that is when I checked on an item and I search the name after that, the checkbox becomes unchecked.

I checked on Heather

[image: listview]

It's unchecked after I search

[image: flitered listview]

How can I ensure that the items are still checked after I search?

CustomAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> implements Filterable {

    private final Activity context;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
    ArrayList<Contact> stringFilterList;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView phoneno;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        ImageView photo;

    }

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom, contacts);
        //super(context, R.layout.custom, contacts);
        this.context = context;
        this.contacts = contacts;
        this.stringFilterList = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    /*@Override
    public String getItem(int position) {

        return contacts.get(position).getName();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return contacts.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }*/

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.phoneno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phoneno);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

            viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    contacts.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.


                    //stringFilterList.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.name, viewHolder.name);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.phoneno, viewHolder.phoneno);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.photo, viewHolder.photo);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkBox, viewHolder.checkBox);

        }
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

        viewHolder.name.setText(contacts.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.phoneno.setText(contacts.get(position).getPhoneNo());
        viewHolder.photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(contacts.get(position).isSelected());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Contact> filterList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                for (int i = 0; i < stringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((stringFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase()).contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        Contact contact = new Contact(stringFilterList.get(i).getName(), stringFilterList.get(i).getPhoneNo());
                        filterList.add(contact);


                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = stringFilterList.size();
                results.values = stringFilterList;
            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            contacts = (ArrayList<Contact>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are supplying new contact list while notifyDataSetChanged so it is unCheck.

Contact contact = new Contact(stringFilterList.get(i).getName(), stringFilterList.get(i).getPhoneNo());
here you are supplying name and phone number, isSelected has default value false

Comment: in `performFiltering` instead of initializing new `Contact` pass your Contact with position like : `filterList.add(contacts.get(i))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your ValueFilter as below

```
private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Contact> filterList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                for (int i = 0; i < stringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((stringFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase()).contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        Contact contact = new Contact(stringFilterList.get(i).getName(), stringFilterList.get(i).getPhoneNo(),**stringFilterList.get(i).isSelected**);
                        filterList.add(contact);


                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = stringFilterList.size();
                results.values = stringFilterList;
            }
            return results;

        }
```

add isSelected value to your new Contact list.

Comment: thanks for you help but I think  filterList.add(stringFilterList.get(i)); will do it.

Answer (score 0):

After search, the current View will be equal position 0. Let see the

```
contacts.get(position).isSelected()
```

return true or false.